# Heroku not Finding Handlebars Partials

Tags: javascript, heroku, handlebars.js, partials

I am completely lost with this problem, I'm sure I must now be being blind but I can't fix it. Heroku is returning a partial could not be found error (below) for a partial that does exist.

**Note:** this all works perfectly on localhost.

Using

- Node: 10.5.0
- Expres: 4.16.3
- Hbs: 4.0.1

File Structure:

```
| > Server
|   > server.js
| > Views
|   > layout.hbs
|   > Partials
|     > pageheader.hbs
```

**server/server.js**

```
let app = express();

hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '\\..\\views\\partials');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('layout.hbs', {
    title: 'Home'
  }
});
```

**views/layout.hbs**

```
...
<body>
    {{> pageheader}}
</body>
...
```

**views/partials/pageheader.hbs**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

and finally...

**Heroku Log**

```
/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:266
throw new _exception2['default']('The partial ' + options.name + ' could not be found');
^
Error: The partial pageheader could not be found
at Object.invokePartial (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:266:11)
at Object.invokePartialWrapper [as invokePartial] (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:68:39)
at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:12:28)
at main (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:173:32)
at ret (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:176:12)
at ret (/app/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:525:21)
at render_file (/app/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:49:23)
at render_with_layout (/app/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:80:5)
at cacheAndCompile (/app/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:151:5)
at /app/node_modules/hbs/lib/hbs.js:171:7
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
```

I appreciate any help / suggestions, I have searched google, read anything I can find that seems to relate. I just don't understand why this works on localhost and not on Heroku.

Comment: Possibly worth noting If I place {{title}} in the layout directly without the reference to the partial. The whole thing does indeed work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I think I have found the problem as the '..' portion of the path.

I have moved server.js to root and altered file references to match that change... it works fine everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the filepath is wrong, try changing

```
__dirname + '\\..\\views\\partials'
```

to

```
__dirname + '/../views/partials'
```

Comment: This wasn't an issue, both are valid and should work.